# Undefined method error when trying to access class property in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a question and correct answer model. I created a single form to fill out both a question and correct answer, with the correct answer being a nested attribute. But, when I want to create a view showing all the questions and answers, I am unable to output the correct answer to its corresponding question.

```
class Question < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :correct_answer
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :correct_answer
end

class CorrectAnswer < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :Question
end

 create_table "questions", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "title"
  end

create_table "correct_answer", force: true do |t|
    t.integer  "question_id"
    t.string  "solution"
  end

<%= form_for @question, url: question_path do |f| %>
<%= f.text_field :title %>
<%= f.fields_for :correct_answer do |q| %>
    <%= q.text_field :solution %>
<% end %>
<% end %>
```

questions_controller:

```
    def show
        @q = Question.all
    end

    def new
        @question = Question.new
        @question.build_correct_answer
    end

    def create
        @question = Question.new(question_params)

        if @question.save
          redirect_to action: "show"
        else
          render action: :new
        end
    end

    private
    def question_params

      params.require(:question).permit(:title, correct_answer_attributes:   [:solution])
    end
end
```

show.html.erb:

```
<% @q.each do |question| %>
<%= question.title %><br />
<% @answer = question.correct_answer %><br />
<%= @answer.solution %>
<%end %>
```

Rendering

```
<% @answer = question.correct_answer %>
```

gives

```
#<CorrectAnswer:0x7d68aa0>
```

which is a class of the correct answer object, but I get

```
undefined method `solution' for nil:NilClass error
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This just means that one or more of your questions from `@q` doesn't have `correct_answer`. You can easily check it like this:

```
<% @q.each do |question| %>
  <%= question.title %><br />
  <% if question.correct_answer.nil? %>
    This question doesn't have a correct answer.
  <% else %>
    <% @answer = question.correct_answer %><br />
    <%= @answer.solution %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

It is also not a good idea to introduce variables inside an `erb` template.

Comment: Can you please suggest the ideal way  to do this

Comment: You mean to get rid of the variable assignment? You can simply output it like this `question.correct_answer.try(:solution)`. Or better, in order to follow [Law of Demeter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_Demeter), introduce `solution` method inside `Question` model: `def solution; correct_answer.try(:solution); end` and call it in your template: `<% @q.each do |question| %> <%= question.title %> <%= question.solution %> <% end %>`